# How to deploy a JEE6 project to Glassfish 3.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

I'm finally ready to stop developing in Eclipse and running on Glassfish and actually deploy this creation onto a web server. I don't know where to begin with this task. How do I get started? I have a MySQL database, some EJBs, Servlets, and Facelets pages and I'm using JPA.

Do I have to save each component into a .jar, .war file or can I put everything into the .war

I exported the EAR project to an EAR and tried deploying it through glassfish admin but it said it was already deployed? does glassfish conginuously deploy working projects so that assembling and packaging isn't required if you're deploying locally?

I go to Glassfish Admin click my application and click "deploy" I fill out the configuration settins and click finish. I'm getting this error:

> An error has occurred
>   Error occurred during deployment: Application with name XRSSear is already registered. Either specify that redeployment must be forced, or redeploy the application. Or if this is a new deployment, pick a different name. Please see server.log for more details.

Sorry I just found out that it was already being deployed as I was testing and running it. I didn't realize that the Glassfish test server environment bundled with eclipse was also a stand alone container server. So all I ended up having to do was find the glassfish "startserver" .bat and run that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish autodeploys EAR projects during testing so the only thing necessary to do is start the glassfish server and it will contain the latest EAR if you're deploying locally to the same Server you're testing on.

Comment: So everyone's links are really unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Carsten's recommendation, I'd like to recommend the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gfirp.html).  The [overview section](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html) describes Java EE packaging.

Comment: turns out I don't need to do that because glassfish was doing it automatically with every build. I just had to start glassfish and it had the current verion of my EAR.

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find more information about application deployment? These
>   resources should help:
>
> - [Application Deployment Guide](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3673)
> - [Deploying an Application](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3193/gehqs/index.html)
>     chapter in the [Quick Start
>     Guide](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3193).
> - [Deployment page](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/deployment/#Supporting_Documentation)
> - [Deployment FAQ](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/deployment/deployment_faq.html)
>     (somewhat older)

**Source**: [FaqDeploymentGeneral](http://wikis.sun.com/display/GlassFish/FaqDeploymentGeneral)

**See also**:
[JEE6 and Packaging an EAR](http://www-02.imixs.com/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/jee6_and_packaging_an_ear) at Ralph's Java Blog.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you open the Glassfish administration page for your server and use it to deploy your application. It's quite easy to use and should be self-explanatory.

Also, I suggest you take a look inside the Glassfish [Application Deployment Guide](http://glassfish.java.net/docs/index.html#allinone).